# Disable link on ant design form submit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, antd

While trying to create a checkout page for my e-commerce site i ran into this issue.

Using ant designs form component, how do you disable a link (continue to delivery) if all the required forms are not filled? Something like this, were the link should be disabled if the phone number field is not filled.

```js
<Form.Item
  name={inputField.phoneNo}
  rules={[
    { required: true, message: "Please input your Phone Number!" },
  ]}
>
  <Input placeholder="Phone Number" />
</Form.Item>

<div>
  <Link to="/Cart">{"<"} return to cart</Link>
  <Form.Item>
    <Link
      to="/Delivery"
      style={{ float: "right" }}
    >
      <Button htmlType="submit">
        Continue to Delivery
      </Button>
    </Link>
  </Form.Item>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

as per Ant design documents you can disable button like following

```
const [form] = Form.useForm();
const [, forceUpdate] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
forceUpdate({});
   }, []);

<Form.Item shouldUpdate={true}>
{() => (
<Button
 type="primary"
 htmlType="submit"
 disabled={!form.isFieldsTouched(false) ||
 form.getFieldsError().filter(({ errors }) => errors.length).length}>
 Log in</Button>)}
 </Form.Item>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can write custom logic for it something like:

```
      <Button             
            disabled={
              !form.isFieldsTouched(true) ||
              form.getFieldsError().filter(({ errors }) => errors.length).length
            } 
            htmlType="submit"
      >
        Continue to Delivery
      </Button>
```

Comment: Yeah i've looked a little into something like that, but i can't seem to get it right. From where do you get form? If i try to paste the above "form" is not recognised..

Comment: When you do **Form.create<component>**, you would get **form** in the props.

Comment: @Jonas  As you are using Antd v4, just import Form from antd and   use dis line  of code (hook) at top of the component.  const [form] = Form.useForm();

Comment: @Hemanthvrm Thanks you for your response. This enables me to use the above solution, however it does not fix the issue, it just disables the button permanently if there are no value in the input fields when the site is rendered (which is always the case). Maybe i wasn't clear enough earlier, but i need a button which either submits the form if the inputs are valid and then redirects the user to the next page. Or it should just invoke the error message to the user that he is missing some fields.

Comment: So irrespective of  button click, u want error message to be displayed directly when user comes to the page if fields are empty?..
You  can make that happen but thats not ideal behaviour and looks odd...
there are 2  best ways for a form ..1) Disable button until user fillout the req fields , Enable when he fill out form ...2) enable button by default, if user clicks button submit just display errors on fields, if he fill the form then errors will be cleared and button will take to next screen

Comment: Let me know what format you are looking for...I can provide sample codebox based on your code

Comment: sorry for the late reply, but no. No error message should be displayed when the user come to the page. However if not all the required fields are filled when the user clicks "Continue to Delivery" an error message below the missing fields should be displayed. However if all the required fields are filled correctly it the button should just redirect the user to the next page :)